# Added row moves to last position once filter is removed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

In NatTable I am adding a row in filtered table.  After removing the filter, the newly added row moves to last position in the table.

But I want to it to stay in the same position, that is next to the row which I added when the table is filtered.

I am currently using the `RowInsertCommand`. I don't want to add row via model or list which used to populated the table. I want to achieve only via NatTable commands. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always hard to follow the explanations and the issue without example code. But I assume you simply copied code from the NatTable examples, so I will explain your issue based on that.

First, the `RowInsertCommand` has several constructors. If you are using a constructor without a `rowIndex` or `rowPosition`parameter, the new object will ALWAYS be added at the end of the list.

When using the filter functionality in NatTable with GlazedLists, the list that is wrapped in the body `DataLayer` is the `FilterList`. If you are operating on the `FilterList` for calculating the `rowIndex` where the new object should be added and have the `FilterList` as base list in the `RowInsertCommandHandler`, the place where the new object is added is transformed between the `FilterList` and the base `EventList`, which might not be the desired result.

To solve this you need to create the `RowInsertCommandHandler` by using the base `EventList`.

```
EventList<T> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(values);
TransformedList<T, T> rowObjectsGlazedList = GlazedLists.threadSafeList(eventList);
SortedList<T> sortedList = new SortedList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList, null);
this.filterList = new FilterList<>(sortedList);

this.baseList = eventList;
bodyDataLayer.registerCommandHandler(new RowInsertCommandHandler<>(this.baseList));
```

The action that performs the add operation then of course needs to calculate the index based on the base `EventList`. The following code is part of the `SelectionAdapter` of an `IMenuItemProvider`:

```
int rowPosition = MenuItemProviders.getNatEventData(event).getRowPosition();
int rowIndex = natTable.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);

Object relative = bodyLayerStack.filterList.get(rowIndex);
int baseIndex = bodyLayerStack.baseList.indexOf(relative);

Object newObject = new ...;
natTable.doCommand(new RowInsertCommand<>(baseIndex + 1, newObject));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Sorry I did not provided which constructor I am using. I am using 'new RowInsertCommand(ILayer layer, int rowPosition, T... objects)'

Comment: I tried the code, it worked as expected. Thanks Sir.